# Blender 2.8 - can't see objects outline on default mode

Tags: modeling

i recently downloaded Blender 2.80 (have been previously using version 2.79). everything was going great, however, suddenly, i selected objects and they weren't outlined. i realized that i do select the objects (since when i move them it works), but i don't know which object im selecting. this is only happening in the default mode tab. on the other modes (compositing, uv editing) everything is perfect, the outlines of the objects are there. i tried resetting to factory settings, however, when reopening my project, the problem is still there. and, as i mentioned, this is only happening on default mode. what have i done? how can i fix this? thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the viewport overlay to outline selected:

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for replying! it is already selected /: